# Select items where their amount is greater than 5

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have no idea why it doesn't work... I need to select particular rows, where their amount is greater than 5.

```
SELECT member, COUNT(DISTINCT member) as membs 
  FROM myDB
  WHERE membs>5
  GROUP BY membe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT member, COUNT(member) as membs 
FROM myDB
GROUP BY membe
HAVING COUNT(member) > 5
```